# Segfault when throwing std::runtime_error on Ubuntu Xenial with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, libtorch

I am having a very strange behavior with Rcpp together with libtorch.

I have a file with 2 functions:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <Rcpp.h> 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_error () {  
  throw std::runtime_error("hi this is my error");
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_error2 () {  
  Rcpp::Rcout << torch::arange(1) << std::endl;
}
```

When I call `test_error()` I get a segfault (g++):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The clang++ error is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`test_error2` works as expected.

This error happens only on Ubuntu Xenial. I tested with Ubuntu Trusty and MacOS and no segfaults.

If I remove the code for `test_error2` from the file, I don't have any error, even if I don't remove the `#include <torch/torch.h>` line.

Also tested compiling with clang++ and g++. Same error.

I created a smalll repo [here](https://github.com/dfalbel/testerror) with the minimal example I could make.

Does anyone have any idea of what this could be?

> **Note** configure file will download and install libtorch automatically from pytorch's website. So don't install the package if you don't want this.

Comment: I added the call stack. The most minimal example I could get is an R package. I don't think this fits here.

Comment: @VTT For `Rcpp` users, this would be an acceptable way of providing a minimal example; if you have torch, the C++ code in the post is compilable and provides functions callable from R that (presumably) can reproduce OP's error for someone running Xenial, and toy R packages in GitHub repos demonstrating issues are often linked to as well

Comment: @DanielFalbel I can also reproduce this on my machine running Ubuntu Bionic, though I do not get an error when I use a standalone C++ file with only the `Rcpp` include and the code for `test_error()` then call `test_error()` after compiling with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, I should have added this to the question. If I remove the code for `test_error2` from the file I don't get any error. Even if including `torch/torch.h`.

Comment: @VTT sorry `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)` is what happens when I execute de program.

Comment: Naive question:  why do you need an external torch library?  What happens when you use the one from the distro?  I see `libtorch3-dev` on my Ubuntu box.

Comment: Despite the name they don't seem to be the same libraries. I am using libtorch which is the tensors library behind https://pytorch.org/ and libtorch3-dev seems to be something else.

Comment: That’s not a segfault; it’s an exception (but not the one you tried to `throw`!) that isn’t being handled.

Comment: @DavisHerring I am sorry. I found a lot of people with this exeption when they were trying to access out of bounds elements in arrays, so I thought it was a segfault. I am still new to c++.

Comment: @DanielFalbel: `bad_alloc` indicates memory exhaustion; `length_error` indicates an attempt to exceed a limit on container size (for which no allocation was even attempted).

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks! I still have no idea of what could be causing this... What kind of interaction between Rcpp and libtorch could cause throwing a runtime error behave like a bad_alloc

Comment: C++ ABIs sometimes bite. It sounds like something that _might_ go away if all C++ libraries were compiled with the same compiler.  If there is a _C_ interface to libtorch try using that -- these typically pose fewer problems between build  setups.

Comment: Right! I'll try to compile libtorch from source using the same compiler as Rcpp. I found some issues on libtorch: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-linking-with-libtorch-c-11-abi/29510 Maybe just using an older version of g++ will do the job.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that compiling the package with an older version `g++` worked fine.

I installed `g++-4.9`:

`sudo apt-get install g++-4.9`.

Edited the `.R/Makevars` to use `g++-4.9`:

```
CXX=g++-4.9
CXX11=g++-4.9
```

Then recompiled Rcpp and the package.

Comment: Yes, a known issue some of us (Hi, @duckmayr) hinted at.  If you `configure` script pulls prebuilt components you should also check that their use is feasible. I am sure there are some macros and tests out there...  (I didn't downvote BTW.)

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't have solved without your help. I had no idea it could be the compiler version. (also didn't know what's an ABI). What you mean is that I should check if the the compiler is compatible in the configure script and raise an error if not?

Comment: You are pulling in a prebuild _C++_ library and those don;t travel well across major versions so at a minimum I'd bark if `clang` is detected or if `g++` of a different (major) version is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing

```
throw std::runtime_error("hi this is my error");
```

with what our docs suggest you do (in an Rcpp-called function, no less)

```
Rcpp::stop("hi this is my error");
```

and see what happens?

Comment: FWIW, that was one of my first thoughts, and when I tried it the same thing happened; OP's mileage may vary

Comment: Right on.  So back to suspecting ABI mixups?